# Buscar coincidencias no exactas en una matriz

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy trabajando sobre una API de personajes y gracias al método `.filter()` pude resolver como encontrar dichos personajes por estado o por episodio donde figuran.

Ahora, a la hora de buscarlos por nombre el método `filter` solo encuentra si cuando busco ingresamos exactamente el mismo nombre.

Por ejemplo:

Si el personaje se llama "Rick Sanchez" y a la hora de buscar pongo "rick" osea el nombre no completo y sin la mayúscula no me lo encuentra.

¿Cómo podría corregir esto?

Edito y agrego el ejemplo del código que estoy usando:

De esta forma me lo toma (pero no es la idea):

```
filtradoPorNombre = episodiosFiltrados.filter(e => e.name === 'Rick Sanchez')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo normalizar la cadena de entrada, convertirla a minúsculas y, posteriormente, compararla con la cadena también normalizada y convertida a minúsculas que estás buscando.

En el siguiente ejemplo te muestro cómo hacerlo:

```js
const episodiosFiltrados = [
  { name: 'Rick Sanchez' },
  { name: 'Rick & Morty' },
  { name: 'Terminator 2' },
];

function normalizar(palabra) {
  return palabra.normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .toLowerCase();
}

filtradoPorNombre = episodiosFiltrados.filter(elemento => 
  normalizar(elemento.name)
    .includes(normalizar('rick'))
);
console.log(filtradoPorNombre);
```

Para empezar, he usado [`String.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) para normalizar los caracteres (convierte `Á` en `A`, `é` en `e`, etc) y luego [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) para convertir el texto en minúsculas.

Por último, he usado la función [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) para comprobar si el nombre contiene el texto que estamos buscando.

Como ambas cadenas estarán normalizadas, la comprobación será mucho más flexible.

Comment: Pude resolverlo con esto! Gracias.